# How to Prevent Windows Mail from Being Replaced by Outlook

Tags: windows, email-client

Windows 10/11 came with a default Mail app, which became my preferred email client on Windows due to its simplicity and allowing me to connect to various email accounts. However, even without toggling the "Try the new Outlook" button, it was eventually forcefully replaced by Outlook when I tried to launch it.

Inspired by a [forum answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-switch-back-to-windows-10-mail-app-from/2d744932-9980-4c8b-b8ba-7ec544a8d6f0), I uninstalled Outlook, but the Mail app still wasn't launching, it would just quit. Then I found the [Mail and Calendar](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRFHVQM?hl=en-us&gl=US) app on the Microsoft store which told me that it was already installed but it had an update, so I updated it. Then on the second launch attempt after that, I got the Mail app back!

However, it's already warning me again that it will soon be replaced by Outlook once more:

[image]

Has anyone found a way to prevent this from happening and *permanently keep* the Mail app, even without updates? Note that I only care about the Mail app, not Calendar. Thank you!

**Note**: I already managed to restore the Mail app, not asking for that. What I need is a way to make it *permanent*, i.e. to prevent it from automatically switching to Outlook, with no return. Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, the Mail app has been replaced and superseded by the new free Outlook app Microsoft released some months back, similar to how Apple has replaced iTunes with Apple Devices and Apple Music. The same is true for Office 365's Outlook program, albeit with that, uninstalling the Outlook UWP app and reinstalling Office 365 allows switching back to the Office 365 Outlook program, however I don't believe the same is true for Mail since Microsoft is trying to unify the user experience and get rid of the disparate apps serving double duty with less functionality.

Comment: An option is to switch to a completely different mail program. BlueMail for Windows is similar to Microsoft Mail, and Thunderbird is considered to be a really good free mail client too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to permanently keep the Mail app,
as Microsoft has pulled the plug.
It will finally stop working by the end of 2024.
Microsoft has decreed that Mail will be replaced by the
new Outlook, and that seems final.

What you can try, which if successful will give you time until
end 2024 to either find a replacement mail app or get used to
Outlook:

- After Outlook has started, click to turn off the "New Outlook" experience.
  From then on, you might be able to start the Windows Mail app.
- From the Microsoft Store, download the old Mail client, which
  might still serve during all of 2024.
  (See [link](https://www.neowin.net/news/the-old-windows-mail-app-is-working-again-but-not-for-long/).)

Answer (score 0):

I can't use the Outlook Desktop App because it doesn't support Exchange ActiveSync. I've had to do the following several times. (Every time Windows updates it re-installs Outlook) and eventually this workaround won't work (End of year). This is the simplest way I've found to get Windows Mail working again.     Go to Settings, then, Apps, then Installed Apps. Find and uninstall Outlook. At this point if you try to use Windows Mail it will still just shut down as soon as you open it. While still in Installed Apps, scroll up to Mail and Calendar. Click on the three dots and choose advanced options. Scroll down and choose reset (not repair) After it finishes resetting, close Settings and open Windows Mail and wait a few seconds. A box will pop up "Allow Mail to access your calendar"? Choose YES. Then another box "Allow Mail to access your contacts" Choose YES. Then another box "Allow Mail to access and send emails? Choose YES. These three boxes have been in random order on some resets. Just answer YES to all three. Then you'll get a message "Outlook is replacing Mail and Calendar" Choose "Not Now" I've done this several times and each time, my email account reappeared in Windows Mail with no information missing. This avoids having to download and re-install the Windows Mail App, AND having to add your email account back into the App.

Comment: Is your `Return` key broken?