# Outlook (new) broken notifications

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, calendar, notifications

Recently I've had to switch to the "Outlook (new)" app. I only want to use this as a calendar, like I used to be able to with the built in "Calendar" app. I have added the relevant accounts (one gmail, one outlook), and they are syncing properly. But despite my best efforts I can't get the notifications to behave properly.

My notifications are set up like in the image below.

What I experience in practice though, is that new mail notifications are *always* popping up. Calendar notifications are only showing when I explicitly run the app.

The app is updated (v1.2024.306.400) and running on an updated Windows 10 (19045.4170)

[image]

Comment: Why not revert to the old Outlook? Because of all the problems of the new Outlook, Microsoft will keep the old one around for a few more years.

Comment: @harrymc I never used the old Outlook. I used the "Mail and Calendar" app, and _only_ for the calendar. That one was built into Windows 10 at some point, but is now entirely deprecated. Trying to launch it, launches Outlook (new) instead.

Comment: Is your problem the same as [How to Prevent Windows Mail from Being Replaced by Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/1829874/how-to-prevent-windows-mail-from-being-replaced-by-outlook)?

Comment: @harrymc I don't necessarily need the old Calendar app (though that would be nice too). But I would like notifications to work properly in the "new" and "better" app :) I guess I'm mainly trying to figure out if this is a known problem, with workarounds/fixes, or whether I've encountered a new bug. It is however very hard to google, considering that there are now at least 4 products with the Outlook branding.

Comment: In Outlook settings, General section, click Notifications in the sub menu. Is "Send me desktop notifications" turned on, and "Notification Style" is not set to "None"?

Comment: @harrymc I reapplied all notification settings to be extra sure. It seems that email notifications are now not happening anymore (as intended!), but calendar notifications are still only happening while the Outlook app is open.

Comment: This is a well-known problem with Outlook, in that it has to be running all the time, but which didn't exist with the old apps. If you can't live with it running minimized all the time, you need to look for a third-party replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the option via Settings>General>Notifications>Notify me about>Calendar?

[image]