# Windows 10 Taskbar Calendar doesn't sync

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, calendar

After being forced to switch to the new mail and calendar app, my taskbar calendar no longer syncs. The events in the taskbar calendar are outdated. Before, I can sync the calendar by opening the (now old) calendar app where I have configured it to use the calendar that is linked to my gmail account. But now every time I try opening the calendar app it just opens the new mail and calendar app instead. Interestingly, the new mail and calendar app does have the updated version of the calendar. So how do I get the taskbar calendar events to update?

Comment: This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1829887/8672) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to access the old calendar app. Instead of trying to open the calendar app directly, I first opened the old mail app, which automatically redirected me to the new Outlook app. I then switched off the new Outlook to go back to the old mail app. Now that I'm back in the old mail app, I then clicked the calendar icon in the bottom left to access the old calendar app, and by doing so my calendar events are now synced again.